# What is the standard format for a .h file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, code-organization

I am wondering what the standard layout/format is for an Objective-C interface (.h) file. I know what components are present within this file, but I have seen them laid out in many different ways.

A lot of the components of an interface file are pretty obvious like the `#import`, `@class`, etc. But for something like the `@protocol` and `@interface` declarations it can be different. I have seen people declare a new protocol above the interface declaration with its implementation of methods below:

```
@protocol MyNewClassDelegate;

@interface MyNewClass : UIViewController

// Properties and Methods

@end

@protocol MyNewClassDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)method

@end
```

The other way that I've seen it is by just having the entire `@protocol` declaration and implementation above the `@interface` statement. So it'd be something like this:

```
@protocol MyNewClassDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)method

@end

@interface MyNewClass : UIViewController

//Properties and Methods

@end
```

I have also seen it setup where one protocol is declared and implemented above the interface while another one is also declared and implemented below.

My question is which one is preferred or is a standard in the industry? Is there some kind of way you organize it based around what its functionality accomplishes?

Comment: you can use anyone of them as long as they are correct, i dont think there is any guideline for where to declare a delegate.

Comment: Generally, I do imports, defines, @classes, protocols, and interfaces, in that order.  But sometimes you might want to keep related pieces together more.

Comment: This is a style question, and therefore primarily opinion based.  Whatever is most readable for you or your employer is the "standard" when it comes to code formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how my answer is more right than others, but this is what i do in most of my applications.

```
#import 
#import

#define
#define

typedef
typedef

@class ClassName
@class ClassName

@protocol ProtocolName;

@interface Name : inheritedObject <FirstProtocolSupported, SecondProtocolSupported, etc>

@property (noantomic, strong) IBOutlet Object* name;
@property (noantomic, strong) IBOutlet Object* name;
@property (noantomic, strong) IBOutlet Object* name;

@property (nonatomic, strong) Object* name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Object* name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Object* name;

- (IBAction)actionName:(SenderObject*)sender;
- (IBAction)actionName:(SenderObject*)sender;
- (IBAction)actionName:(SenderObject*)sender;

- (type)methodName:(Parameter*)argument;
- (type)methodName:(Parameter*)argument;
- (type)methodName:(Parameter*)argument;

@end

@protocol ProtocolName <ProtocolThatIsImplmented>

- (type)protocolMethod:(Param*)parameter;

@end
```

in essence it's, import statements then, #define statements then, typedef statements, @class statements then, any protocols, then class declaration, then iboutlet properties, then normal properties, then inaction methods, then normal actions, then the protocol declaration.

All in all there is no correct way to order the code in the .h file, it's all a matter of preference, as long as everything is declared accurately

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The reason I brought it up was because I started looking at the .h file for Apple classes like UITableView and UICollectionView. They have different setups and I just wanted to get some opinions on it. Also is there a reason why you would declare typedefs before the `@class` statement? I ask because `@class` statements are essentially a branch of functionality for what #import does. Would it make sense to have them right underneath the #imports?

Comment: (at)class basically says that, this class exists but i'm not importing it. So in essence it does nothing. I try to keep all my import statements in the .m file, so i can use (at)class, for declaring that a class exists and make properties/methods, but it won't know what that class is until i import it, in the .m file.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't any correct (or even preferred) convention for writing your `.h` files. Header files are typically very short, unless you have scores of properties and methods (as is the case with many of Apple's Foundation and UIKit classes). Even the most unwieldy header files generally don't exceed several hundred lines of code, so there's not much to worry about.

However, sometimes your protocol and its class will be codependent. In other words, the protocol needs to be aware of the class, and the class needs to be aware of the protocol.

For instance, `UITableView` needs to know about the protocols `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`, since it defines properties which must conform to those protocols (namely, `delegate` and `dataSource`). However, each of those protocols also need to know about `UITableView` since they both require a `UITableView` as a parameter for many of their methods (such as `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`).

In this scenario, your second example (declaring the protocol in its entirety before the class) wouldn't suffice unless you used a forward `@class` declaration ahead of the `@protocol` definition. Your first example *would* work, because you are using a forward `@protocol` declaration ahead of the class.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer my protocols to be in their own .h file. That way they can easily be reused.

You also wouldn't have to worry about the 'order' of things when you #import it.

```
//Copyright & license
#import 
#import "AProtocol.h"
#import "Typedefs.h"
#import "NeededConsts.h"

@class ClassName;
@class ClassName;

@interface Name : inheritedObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) Object* name;

- (type)methodName:(Parameter*)argument;
- (void)setDelegate:(id <AProtocol>)argument;

@end
```

Inside the Name.m file (I try to keep as much info as possible out of the .h file)

```
//Copyright & license
#import ...
#import "ProtocolName.h"

file wide typedef
file wide typedef

@class ClassName;
@class ClassName;

static const NSInteger cFileWideInt = 404;

@interface Name () <FirstProtocolSupported, SecondProtocolSupported, etc>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet Object* name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet Object* name;
@property (weak,   nonatomic) id<AProtocol> delegate;

@end

@implementation
@end
```

The benefit of having most of your properties and declarations inside of your .m file is that it provides 'encapsulation' for information that your other classes don't need to know. This point leads into code architecture which would turn this into a long and complex answer ;P